# Indesign style combining underlined text and spaces

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, cs5, style

How can I make a style combining underlined text and non underlined spaces with Indesign cs5?

Thank you for helping.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a new character style and call it "Not Underlined". Set the Underline color in its Underline Options to "None". To be able to do so, you *must* temporarily enable underline! Then, after setting the color, set underline back to its default 'indeterminate' state.
2. Add a GREP style to the paragraph style you are using here. Set the text to match to

   ```
   \s+
   ```

   (meaning "all whitespaces"), and set the matching character style to your just-created "Not Underlined".
3. Sit back and enjoy the result:

[image: look! no underlined spaces!]

Why not simply set "underline off" in that GREP style? Because it would only work if the underline is applied in your paragraph style. Overriding the paragraph default, either *entirely* manual (a local override) or with a Character Style (the 'correct' way as far as I'm concerned) will *always* override a GREP style.

---

This assumes you used paragraph styles to format your text. If you did not, consider the advantages of doing so (where being able to casually switch off underlined spaces document-wide would count as one).

If you choose to not use paragraph styles, you must select your entire text and apply the GREP Style as a local override to everything.